# If the distribution of $X$ is defined conditionally on variables $Z,W$, and we only use $W$ to estimate $X$, can $E(X)$ be defined?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X,Z,W$ are random variables and that we are interested in estimating the expectation of $X$, $E(X)$. Suppose that the distribution of $X$ is defined as:

$$
X\mid Z=z, W=w \sim \mathcal{F}_{Z,W}
$$

That is, $X$ is conditionally defined with respect to values of $Z$ and $W$. Suppose now that we would like to find $E(X)$ through a sampling procedure

$$
E(X)=E_{W}\bigg(E_{Z\mid W}\left(E\bigg(X\mid Z,W\bigg)\mid W\right)\bigg)
$$

If a sampling procedure were to be taken, it would be

1. Draw a value of $w$ from the distribution of $W$.
2. Draw a value of $z$ from the conditional distribution of $Z\mid W$.
3. Draw a value of $x$ from the conditional distribution of $X\mid Z,W$.

I would then like to know what happens if we **instead** do the following procedure:

$$
E_{W}\bigg(E\bigg(X\mid W\bigg)\bigg)
$$

That is, we

1. Draw a value of $w$ from the distribution of $W$.
2. Draw a value of $x$ from the conditional distribution of $X\mid W$.

By the iterated expectations, or the tower property, the above should be equal to $E(Y)$. However, I am unsure if such a thing can be defined, and what this sort of phenomena is normally referred to.

For example, if the issue is that $X$ needs $Z,W$ to be defined, we can rewrite as:

$$
E\bigg(X\mid W=w\bigg)= \sum_z E\bigg(X\mid W, Z=z\bigg)P\left(Z=z\mid W=w\right)
$$

Would it then be a sum of distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first 3-steps procedure would give you a triple $(x,z,w)$ which should correspond to a realization of the joint variables $(X,Z,W)$, because $f_{X,Z,W}=f_{X\mid Z,W} f_{Z \mid W} f_W$. Computing the sample average of many values of $x$ you would get (under some assumptions; namely, finite variance) an estimator of $E[X]$.

There's actually no need of invoking the iterated expectations property.

Similarly, your second 2-steps procedure would give you a pair $(x,w)$ which should correspond to a realization of the joint variables $(X,W)$. Again, computing  the sample average of many values of $x$ you would get another estimator of $E[X]$.

In any case, you are producing samples of a multivariate variate , one of which is $X$, the one you are interested in. It would be equivalent (not only for estimating the expectation!) to produce $X$ by computing the marginal $f_X = \int \int f_{X,Z,W} dz dw = \int \int f_{X\mid Z,W} f_{Z \mid W} f_W dz dw$

Perhaps in some case the three (or two) step procedure turns to be numerically, simpler in terms of random variable generation...

It's not clear for me what is your doubt.

You seem to believe that, because there is a conditional density, then there is some "dependence" that you need to include in your generation process. But if you are interested in $X$, of course you can use the marginal density directly.

Here's an example (forget about the three variables, your conceptual issue applies also to two vars).

Suppose that $ W$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $X|W$ is uniform on $[0,W]$.

Then, a simple recipe for generating samples of $X$ is to generate first a random $W$ (uniform on $[0,1]$) and then produce a random $X$ uniformly on $[0,W]$.

This works, of course (not only to estimate expectations, also for estimating any moment, or the full distribution of $X$).

But we could also compute

$$f_X(x) = \int f_{X,W} dW = \int f_{X|W} f_W dW =\int \frac{1}{w} [0\le x \le w] [0\le w \le 1] dw =\\
= \int_x^1 \frac{1}{w} dw= -\log(x) \,\, [0\le x \le 1] $$

If you forget about $W$, and you are told that $X$ follows this density, you can produce a random $X$ according to this density - and, of course, it will have the same properties as the previous procedure.

In this (particular) case, the two step procedure happens to be a little simpler
and perhaps more efficient.

Comment: What would be the difference between the estimation procedure done off  the 3-steps procedure vs. just estimating $X$? Would I be correct to say that for the purposes of the expectation, both are consistent and unbiased for $E(X)$, BUT that the variance will be different?

Comment: The three step procedure makes sense only if you have those conditional probabilities. Even then, it's not necessary: it should be simpler to compute the marginal $f_X = \int \int f_{X,Z,W} dz dw = \int \int f_{X\mid Z,W} f_{Z \mid W} f_W dz dw$ and use that for producing samples of $X$. No difference at all (for estimating the mean, or whatever).

Comment: Example added...